# How to make a Discord bot active another bots?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I use Python to made a Discord bot to "auto-fishing"(Tatsu's fishing game) by sending "t!fish".
But when it sent the message, Tatsu didn't response. Is it possible to make a bot like a user?

Comment: Some bots disable interactions with bots, You can use a user token but that is against TOS of discord

Comment: That's a bad idea.  Get some unstoppable bot-on-bot action raging on, flood the server  --  https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/feb/23/wikipedia-bot-editing-war-study

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task you want your bot to do is impossible because the discord API implicitly makes sure bots dont to react to commands sent by other bots.
Since if it could you would be able to spam other bots.

The only way you can get over this is by giving your bot a user TOKEN instead of a bot TOKEN but then the user TOKEN you use will get banned.

Answer (score 0):

Taking it from RandomGuy's answer. Usually, most bot creators don't allow code to execute for a bot with an `if message.bot: return`, the same applies to commands.command(). The API does not take control of the commands. Commands are done on the code like `on_message`.

A self bot would be needed but this is against the [TOS](https://discord.com/terms) which requires a user token instead of a bot one. This can lead to your accounts being permanently banned. Discord.py is removing self bot support entirely from it and in the current versions, most features don't work.